# Chrome extension tabs sendMessage from background to contentscript errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    });
});
```

This sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't.

Cases that don't work:

1) When I reload the extension and click the extension icon on an existing tab
2) When I add a breakpoint inside background.js

Cases that do work:

1) When I reload the extension and reload/load new tab and no breakpoints are added inside background.js

The errors thrown are usually:

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. lastError:29
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
at chrome-extension://glbcapgiojbbnjhngjdmoglaamjbjjak/background.js:16:28
at <error: illegal access>
at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect (miscellaneous_bindings:258:27)
```

Can anybody shed some light on this? I find it particularly strange that breakpoints would cause it to fail (almost as if pausing background.js will cause the event listener to die)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out when a breakpoint is set in background.js, the tabs object becomes:

```
0: Object
active: true
favIconUrl: ""
highlighted: true
id: 20
incognito: false
index: 0
pinned: false
selected: true
status: "complete"
title: "Developer Tools - chrome-extension://glbcapgiojbbnjhngjdmoglaamjbjjak/_generated_background_page.html"
url: "chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html dockSide=right&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)"
windowId: 19
```

The event listener is in a different tab, and so "receiving end does not exist". Having said that, I need to figure out a way to send the message to the correct tab (I also do some redirecting with oauth2 so it also messes with the tab selection).

Answer (score 1):

I guess..Due to breakpoint, focus moves to background script.
You used chrome.tabs.query function with {active: true, currentWindow: true}, but background script does not have tabid.
If you want to debug using breakpoint, you should make a point at inside of callback function.